# Is JSON Web Token (JWT) safe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I'm new to programing and currently learning JavaScript, NodeJS with Express. I heard about JWT, but many people told me "its unsecure", "use sessions instead". But it doesn't seem more secure for me?

So I was wondering: How are you making your websites safe when using a login-area? Is JWT really unsafe?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Who are these "many people?"

Comment: I've been of the opinion to use JWT for authorisation, not for authentication- this guy does a decent job of explaining JWT - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Q17ubqLfaM

Comment: JWT is perfectly safe, storing in localStorage and/or transmitting over non-HTTPS is what makes it insecure